# MS Access pie charts - base query advice?

Tags: ms-access, charts, ms-office

I have some data that I want to display in a chart:

```
Theme    Type    Count(Type)
Blah1    1        5
Blah1    2        5
Blah1    3        8
Blah2    1        1
Blah3    2        5
Blah3    3        10
Blah4    1        111
Blah4    2        222
Blah4    3        333
```

I want to display that query data in a Pie Chart, one chart for each theme with a section of pie for each Type (with the value of the count determining the size).  Unfortunately my mind has gone blank.  Everything I try does not appear correctly, some queries also require an repeated entry of the parameters but even if I do that it doesn't display correctly.  I think I need to write another query to the format:

```
Theme   Type1   Type2    Type3    Type4   
Blah1   5       5        8        1
Blah2   1
Blah3   5       10
Blah4   111     222      333
```

Is that correct and does that make sense?  If it isn't correct how else do I do it?

I haven't done charts before and I am struggling a bit - many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your data in columns. This is what I did. You can see the selection I had when I inserted the pie chart:
[image: Pie chart excel]

For more charts you can either copy the data and just replace the last column with the numbers. Or you could also copy the inserted chart and change the source data (when you click on the pie part you see the source data in the worksheet - you can drag it to a new area).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a **crosttab query** to produce the data in the following format, as you suggest it needed to be in the similar column layout:

```
Theme   Type1   Type2    Type3    Type4   
Blah1   5       5        8        1
Blah2   1
Blah3   5       10
Blah4   111     222      333
```

I am relatively experienced with Access - just not charts unforunately!! Seems so simple :(